# installing getopts.pl into the perl installation

Tags: software-installation, perl

I need to install `getopts.pl` into my Perl installation. The software I use request that `getopts.pl` should be part of the Perl installation or my path need to be appropriately pointing to the paths of my Perl installation. How can I maintain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getopts.pl` is part of the package `libperl4-corelibs-perl`

```
sudo apt-get install libperl4-corelibs-perl
```

---

**Why?**

*This is why:*

```
% apt-file search getopts.pl
libperl4-corelibs-perl: /usr/share/perl5/getopts.pl
```

Comment: it gives me this warning:

Comment: which warning do you mean?

Comment: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:libx11-dev, libxau-dev, libxdmcp-dev, x11proto-input-dev

Comment: Start `sudo apt-get install -f` However, this is a new problem and has nothing to do with your original question. If the problem with the said command is not resolved, you should ask another question and you could give me a link. I'll be looking at the problem then gladly.